# Wagtail with get_full_url is redirecting to non SSL link

Tags: python, django, http, https, wagtail

I am using get_full_url to get the link of pages in my wagtail application but it redirects from HTTPs to HTTP, when I changed it to get_url or pageurl in templates, it fixed the problem and all links were redirected to HTTPs (SSL)
the only problem that I faced is in the footer as it is sent in email, and it creates a server error every time I send an email with the footer bein using pageurl
this is the error that I got:

```
    raise ValueError("pageurl tag expected a Page object, got %r" % page)

Exception Type: ValueError at /mission/accept_plan/
Exception Value: pageurl tag expected a Page object, got ''
```

which does not happen with get_full_url

here the code in the template:

```html
<a href="{% pageurl LIBRARY %}" referrerpolicy="origin">
```

library is being defined in context as this

```py
library = (
        Site.find_for_request(request)
        .root_page.get_children()
        .type(LibraryPage)
        .first()
    )

return {
        "LIBRARY": library,
        }
```

when I changed to this syntaxe:

```html
<a href="{{ LIBRARY_URL }}" referrerpolicy="origin">
```

```py
library = (
        Site.find_for_request(request)
        .root_page.get_children()
        .type(LibraryPage)
        .first()
    )

return {
        "LIBRARY_URL": library.get_full_url(),
        }
```

with this last syntax no server error but it redirects to https when I am on the website

is there a way to fix the get_full_url to redirect to HTTPs links only?
thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the admin, under Settings -> Sites, set your site's port number to 443.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply
is there a better way to use the file settings (base.py)
I am trying to find out about it in the documentation: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#site-model-ref

Comment: also now reading about it here in the documentation: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/sitemaps.html?highlight=443#setting-the-hostname

Comment: I changed the port in sites but it did not fix the problem, it keeps showing HTTP:
```python
>>> for site in Site.objects.all():
...     site.port=443
...     site.save()
```

Comment: opening a new private window has fixed the problem, clearing the cache on my browser did not fix it, I think it is maybe due to cookies,
your answer has resolved the issue indeed, thank you very much